# How to put code inside an R markdown environment?

Tags: r, r-markdown

R markdown has environments such as [example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems).
Is there a way to have a multi-line code with triple ` inside these environments?
I tried adding an extra ` in the the example environment, but it get confused when the environments close, and the text after the code gets into the code block.

[Here is what I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI8lS.png)

and

[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jklIW.png)

Comment: Do you want the inner code evaluated or just printed?

Comment: At the moment I only need it to be printed, but it would be interesting to know how to do the evaluation too, perhaps for later.

Comment: Try <https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/verbatim-code-chunks.html> additionally in raw markdown you could do ~~~ before and after the code chunk

Comment: I do not actually want the word "C++" (in my case) to appear in the result, unlike in the link. Only the content of what's in the C++ code block should appear. At the moment I am achieving this by just having an example environment and separately a C++ code block. It looks ok, but semantically, my code block is part of the example, so I think it should be within the example environment.

The ~~~ resulted in a strikethrough...

I'm very new to (R)markdown, coming from latex, so sorry if I don't make sense. I have tried to find solutions in that link but failed so far.